# Mogrify subfolders and keep original directory structure

Tags: batch-file, graphicsmagick, mogrify

I have files structure with subdirectories and image files inside. I want to use GraphicsMagick to convert image files to another format (and make them smaller). I can do it with simple command like this:

```
mogrify -path ../img-converted -format jpg ../content/*.jpg
```

But things get complicated, when I try to preserve subdirectory structure. Mogrify doesn't have this option, so I need to write shell script to check all directories (and maybe create new ones).

How this should be done?

Comment: Most of us don't have access to GraphicsMagics, so we are only left to guess what you are referring to regarding folder structure.  If you can provide an example of a 'before' structure and 'after' result someone might be able to help.

Comment: I meant GraphicsMagick, sorry. With mogrify command inside GraphicsMagick you can convert files inside one folder into another. But I can't do similar task, with keeping subfolders structure.

Comment: See some links on recursion at http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=25862

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me - it resizes all jpg files in the current folder and all subfolders, while preserving the folder structure:

```
find -iname '*.jpg' -exec mogrify -sampling-factor 4:2:0 -strip -quality 85 -interlace JPEG -colorspace sRGB -resize '2560x2560>' {} +
```

Answer (score 1):

Supposing Windows OS as question tagged `batch-file`.

At first, using `robocopy` to copy all subfolder structure from *source* folder to the *destination* one. Then, looping through *source* folder and recurse it's subfolders, get full source and target (*sub*)paths and echo them. As not sure in `mogrify` using therefore `@echo mogrify ...` formulated in terms of my (*mis*)understanding it...

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
@SETLOCAL enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set "source=content"
set "target=img-converted"
robocopy %source% %target% nonexistingfilename /E
FOR /R "content" %%G in (.) DO (
  set "sourcefldr=%%~dpnxG"
  set "targetfldr=!sourcefldr:%source%=%target%!"
  @echo !sourcefldr!    !targetfldr!
  if EXIST "!sourcefldr!\*.jpg" (
    @echo mogrify -path !targetfldr! -format jpg !sourcefldr!\*.jpg
    rem surround pathnames with double quotes if necessary as follows
    rem mogrify -path "!targetfldr!" -format jpg "!sourcefldr!\*.jpg"
  )
)
@ENDLOCAL
@goto :eof
```

That `nonexistingfilename` (could be replaced with `^Nul`) in

`robocopy %source% %target% nonexistingfilename /E`

command assures copying *folder* structure *only*, no files. Using `*.jpg` instead will copy all `*.jpg` as well:

`robocopy %source% %target% *.jpg /E`

Comment: I'm on OSX, but your idea looks perfectly fine! First copy all files, and after use mogrify to change sizes. That will work for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The existing Windows answer gives only a single file at a time to `mogrify`, which probably slows it down since it cannot multithread with OpenMP in the same way.

Here is my answer for a batch script. It mogrifies all matching files in the current directory, and then also in all subdirectories (recursively). Save the batch script in your desired directory and then execute it.

```
@echo off
echo MOGRIFY CURRENT DIRECTORY:
@echo on
magick mogrify -transparent white -trim +repage *.png
@echo off
echo:
echo MOGRIFY SUBDIRECTORIES:
@echo on
FOR /D /R %%A IN (*) DO magick mogrify -transparent white -trim +repage "%%A\*.png"
@echo off
echo:
echo SCRIPT COMPLETE
pause
```